# How to assigning dynamic value to CssClass in .aspx page not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I am using server side HyperLink control on webform and want to assign dynamic `CSS` Value to it.

HyperLink  control is inside repeater control

It fails if i use it like this `CssClass='search-<%#Eval("CSS") %>'` and if i do it like this then it works  `CssClass='<%#Eval("CSS") %>'`.

Issue i have is that i have to concatenate `search-` to  field value `<%#Eval("CSS") %>`

How can i define so that value is assigned to it

in HTML source it shows up like this `class="search-<%#Eval("CSS") %>"`

SOLVED it by doing in this manner

`CssClass='<%# Eval("CSS") +"-type-search "%>'`

Answer (score 3):

You need to include whatever text you need to inside <%# %> tag enclosed with ' ' or "" depends on what you used at start of your markup

```
class='<%# "search-" & Eval("CSS") %>'
```